# Entity framework core include warning

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

When EF (2.2 & 3) at query worm up I get following warning:

> *The Include operation for navigation '[x].something' is unnecessary and was ignored because the navigation is not reachable in the final query results.*

I know the cause of it, I'm looking to a solution to suppress it.

What causes it? an extension that returns a new type of list, sort of a book page, object contains the list of items on the page with 3 extra props, total of all items, page and page size.

```
   public static BookPageList<T> ToBookPageList<T>(this IQueryable<T> dataSet, IBookPageFilter filter)
    {
        var result = new BookPageList<T>();
        IQueryable<T> range = dataSet
            .Skip((filter.Page- 1) * filter.PageSize)
            .Take(filter.PageSize);
        result.AddRange(range.ToList());
        result.Total = dataSet.Count(); // here wormup warning happens
        result.PageSize = filter.PageSize;
        result.Page = filter.Page;
        return result;
    }
```

In case data set has includes, warning is shown.

```
 var bookPageItems = dbcontext.Item
    .Include(x => x.NavProp1)
    .Include(x => x.NavProp2)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .ToBookPageList(filter);
```

I want to remove the warnings because it pollutes cloud logs, sometimes are just to many and changing logging verbosity is not an option.

Is there any way how it can be handled in the book page extension method? I really like this extension.

Comment: I see no alternative other than also feeding the source dataset (as an additional parameter) into the method, without the `.Includes`, and without the also unneeded `.OrderBy`. Or calculating the source dataset .Count() outside the method and feeding the count in as a parameter.

Comment: @PeterB I prefer not to, but if there's not other way I will get the count outside of the extension.